# Opening multiple files in C# and checking the contents of every file

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

What I want to do is open multiple files and read in the text from every file and check for certain keywords and print them all into a new file, and once done a new file will be created with all of the keywords. I am already using a foreach to iterate through all the file names and I know how to open multiple files, but what about retrieving the contents and checking certain conditions while simultaneously printing?

Below is just an example of what I have so far, pretty standard stuff.

Thanks guys!

```
  if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // Read the files
            foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
            {

                try
                {

                    listView1.Items.Add(file);

                }
                catch (SecurityException ex)
                {
                    // The user lacks appropriate permissions to read files, discover paths, etc.
                    MessageBox.Show("Security error. Please contact your administrator for details.\n\n" +
                        "Error message: " + ex.Message + "\n\n" +
                        "Details (send to Support):\n\n" + ex.StackTrace
                    );
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Could not load the image - probably related to Windows file system permissions.
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot display the image: " + file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf('\\'))
                        + ". You may not have permission to read the file, or " +
                        "it may be corrupt.\n\nReported error: " + ex.Message);
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: should this be tagged as homework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You read a file using [System.IO.File.ReadAllText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx) like SoMoS suggests. [Search the string in whatever way works best](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228630%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and write the data back out with a [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

To read a file use `System.IO.File.ReadAllText()`. This will put all the content into a string variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try
            Using sr As New StreamReader("TestFile.txt")
                Dim line As String
                Do
                    line = sr.ReadLine()
                    If Not (line Is Nothing) Then
                       Console.WriteLine(line)
                    End If
                Loop Until line Is Nothing
            End Using
        Catch e As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:")
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
        End Try
```

;)